# set two different labels for two different pages that use the same form - symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a form and I need to set labels for two different kind of pages. I tried to used `$this->widgetSchema->setLabels...` with an `if` and with `$sf_params->get('module')` and `$sf_params->get('action')` but I got an error saying that $sf_params is an undefined variable. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, you can pass to renderLabel() the label you want.

```
$form['xxx']->renderLabel('Your label')
```

Comment: thank... I thought that it would messe with `hasError()` if I took the `renderRow()` off.